# frbs subscript out of bounds in MF Array

Tags: r

I have made a piece of code with the frbs Package in R.
When i take the example call it was give this failure:

> "Error in MF[k, temp[1]] : subscript out of bounds"

MF[k... is the Array with the Var of input and output inside, or?

Im a Beginner in R only and have no idea what i must show to eliminate the failure. Can me help anyone?

Here is the example Call:

```
### Beispielsaufruf

### Wert für Wasserstand (zwischen 0 und 43) [Millionen m³]
Wstand<-12
### Wert für Trinkwasserbedarf (zwischen 0 und 200) [m³/s]
Wbedar<-40
### Wert für Energiebedarf (zwischen 0 und 100) [%] (-> normiert auf 1 MW = 100%)
Ebedar<-45

newdata<- matrix(c(Wstand, Wbedar, Ebedar), nrow= 1, byrow = TRUE)
res <- predict(fuzzy.model, newdata)$predicted.val
Error in MF[k, temp[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```